# Blazor pass a javascript object as an argument for IJSRuntime

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I want to pass a `javascript` object that is already existed in a `javascript` file as a parameter to `InvokeVoidAsync` method :

**myJs.js** :

```
var myObject= {a:1,b:2};
```

**MyComponent.razor** :

```
@inject IJSRuntime js

@code {
    private async Task MyMethod()
    {
        await js.InvokeVoidAsync("someJsFunction", /*how to add myObject here? */);
    }
}
```

How to pass `myObject` to the `someJsFunction` function?
(*Note that the function may also should accept c# objects too*)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the trick, simply use the `eval` function :

```
  private async Task MyMethod()
    {
        object data = await js.InvokeAsync<Person>("eval","myObject");
        await js.InvokeVoidAsync("someJsFunction", data );
    }
```

Comment: That helped me. By the way, if you don't have the C# representation of your data structure, you can use the generalized object type. It works, e.g. object data = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("eval", "myJSStruct");

Comment: It's recommended not to use eval.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Never_use_eval!   and     https://swimburger.net/blog/dotnet/communicating-between-dotnet-and-javascript-in-blazor-with-in-browser-samples

Answer (score 0):

in the example below, "someJsFunction" accepts an object of type Person :

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

in my javascript file

```
var myObject = { name: "Pat", age: 38 }; //a person

//this function provides access to myObject
window.getMyObject = () =>
{
    return myObject;
};

window.someJsFunction = (person) =>
{
    console.log(person);
}
```

In the component :

```
@page "/"
@inject IJSRuntime js


<div>
    <button @onclick="MyMethod" >Click</button>
</div>

@code{

    Person Person;

    protected async override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            //retrieve myOject and assign to the field Person
            Person = await js.InvokeAsync<Person>("getMyObject");
        }
    }

    private async Task MyMethod()
    {
        if(Person != null)

        //pass Person to someJsFunction
        await js.InvokeVoidAsync("someJsFunction", Person);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create new obj without any trouble as shown in code below:

```
protected async override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            var obj = new{
                Id2= "Remarks"
            };

            await _js.InvokeVoidAsync("Not.addKeyboardListenerEvent", obj);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You could define a new JS function

```
someJsFunctionWithObj(){
    someJsFunction(myObject);
}
```

Then call that instead...

```
await js.InvokeVoidAsync("someJsFunctionWithObj");
```

Or create a JS function that returns the object -> call that from C# to get it -> then pass it back, but that seems quite convoluted.

It sounds like probably you should rethink your design really... Maybe if you explained why you are actually trying to do this we can suggest better idea?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I want the exact answer to the question. Your answer is just another solution to turn around the problem.

Comment: @nAviD - Well the answer is that is not currently possible in Blazor....